# Extra white spaces while printing my results in textfield and in Textarea

Tags: php, html, echo, space

```
<input type=text name=goTitle value="<?php require'db_connection.inc.php'; $QUERY='SELECT title FROM news_topics WHERE id = '.$_POST['id']; $data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($QUERY)) ;echo$data['title']; ?>">
```

Its Giving me four white spaces before every result , and even trim($string); did not work with me .

Comment: You should check into db_connection.inc.php. Consider splitting presentation (HTML) from logic (queries), or your code will mess up very soon.

Comment: Snap... mixing markup with db stuff is just awful in every way. Add to that that you're `require`-ing a file inside markup + you're using a query that is _extremely_ vulnerable to injection **And** you are using a ***deprecated*** extension and you will, I hope, understand why helping you to fix this issue is not doing you a service, it's helping you write terrible code. Please learn about prepared statements, and the newer (safer and not deprecated) DB extensions first

Comment: I suggest you to post your db_connection.inc.php

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The devil must have written that line of code.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem +1 for a helpful comment to the OP.

Comment: @singe31: Relax, we've all written horrible code while learning, but sadly, it's this kind of code that people associate with PHP, and why it gets a worse rep than it actually deserves. Technically, PHP allows this way of coding, so there's nothing about the language that tells newbies that this really shouldn't be done. Ever.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I know, just joking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your php code out from `input` and get value in variable like this

```
<?php 
require'db_connection.inc.php'; 
$QUERY='SELECT title FROM news_topics WHERE id = '.$_POST['id'];            
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($QUERY)) ;

$title = $data['title']; 
?>
```

Now put this `variable` echo in `input` like this

```
<input type=text name=goTitle value="<?php echo trim($title);?>">
```

**NOTE 1 :**  you are in danger of mysql injection don't put post values directly into your query use some escapes like below

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
// now use $id in your query
```

**NOTE 2 :** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: **Note 3:** `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated, too and it has security fault in case of incorrect encoding (cf the manual).

Comment: @Elias `mysql_*` is also included `mysql_real_escape_string` have you not seen NOTE 2 clearly

Comment: Oh, I have, but the main issue with using it is the security issues you can have in case of incorrect encoding. Perhaps you haven't seen my comment to the question then. Fixing this code in the way that you suggest is like offering a manicure to someone who's about to have his hands cut off. It's pointless. He needs to fix the fundamental flaws. He needs serious refacturing, not a band-aid fix

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem then write an answer with your suggestions i will appreciate it.